# jQuery rotating classes through elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```
<ul class="box">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Now I want to add first `li` class `current` and second class `next`. Then after etc 1 second move the classes "down" so second will have class `current` and third will have class `next`. After 1 second again `current` class to third child and `next` to first. And so on.. forever. But how can I do it? Is there any common solution for doing this?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Da3W5/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function () {
    var $lis = $('.box li'),
        $cur = $lis.first().addClass('current'),
        $next = $cur.next().addClass('next');
    setInterval(function () {
        $cur.removeClass('current');
        $cur = $next.removeClass('next').addClass('current');

        $next = $cur.next();
        if (!$next.length) {
            $next = $lis.first();
        }
        $next.addClass('next');
    }, 1000);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Da3W5/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is js code for that.

```
var index = 0;
```

function InfinitiveSwitching() {
    var items = $(".box li");

```
var previousIndex = index - 1;
if (0 > previousIndex) {
    previousIndex = $(items).length - 1;
}

var previousImage = $(items).get(previousIndex);
$(previousImage).removeClass('current');

var currentImage = $(items).get(index);
$(currentImage).removeClass('second');
$(currentImage).addClass('current');

index++;
if (index >= $(items).length) {
    index = 0;
}
var secondImage = $(items).get(index);
$(secondImage).addClass('second');
window.setTimeout(function () { InfinitiveSwitching() }, 1000)
```

}

Good luck